# DataRow Update .NET

Tags: .net, datatable

I have a question about the datarow and how I can update it...

I have a datatable with two columns, id and name.  I do the following:

```
    // data table has data at this point....

    myTable.Columns.Add("Fri");

    foreach(DataRow r in myTable.Rows) {
        r["Fri"] = 4;

    }
```

What I am trying to do here is add a new columnm, "Fri".  Then for each entry already in the data table I want to have the value in column Fri as 4.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: It appears that in asking the question I found a solution, thanks for replying thou :).

Comment: You need to tell us what's going wrong - are you getting an error? Is it not adding the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you listed should work, but if you want to later use the Fri value as an integer you should declare the data type of the column like this:

```
myTable.Columns.Add("Fri", typeof(int));
```